# Is there a selector that can be used (in Python) to select elements without a tag?

Tags: web-scraping, css-selectors, python-3.6

```
<div id="some id" class="some class">
    <table id="some other id" class="a different class">...</table>
    
        
        I want this text,


    <br>
    
        this text,


    <br>


        along with this text


    </div>
```

I am trying to use Python to web scrape multiple pages with similar code as seen above. I tried using basic Python CSS selectors to grab the text, but I couldn't work it out. I was mainly wondering if there is a selector that can be passed through the Beautiful Soup `select()` method that selects elements that are in `<div>` but not in `<table>`. I tried to select `<br>` (unaware of what it does), but that did not work.

I have minimal knowledge of HMTL, so I apologize for any mistakes in or confusion caused by the above code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually quite simple. After experimenting, I figured out that you can use the following code to get the text of the above HTML.

```
import requests, bs4

#Create a BeautifulSoup Object
url = 'https://url.thisisthewebsitecontainingthehtml.com'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

#Create a list containing all elements with the tag <div>
divElems = soup.select('div[id="some id"]')
#Create an empty list to add the text
trueText = []
for i in divElems:
    text = list(i)
    trueText.append((text[-5].strip(), text[-3].strip(), text[-1].strip()))
```

Python's `list()` function divides the selected HTML into individual 'chunks' - everything under the `<table>` tag, the first bit of text, the `<br>` tag, the next bit of text, the other `<br>` tag, and the last bit of text. Since we only want the 'chunks' containing text, we add the '-1'st, '-3'st, and '-5'st element of the `text` list into our `trueText` list.

Executing this code will create a list, `trueText` containing the desired text from the above HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to simply remove the child table tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div id="some id" class="some class">
    <table id="some other id" class="a different class">not this</table>


        I want this text,


    <br>

        this text,


    <br>


        along with this text


    </div>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
soup.select_one('[id="some other id"]').extract()
print(soup.select_one('[id="some id"]').text)
```